# how to increment a decimal/float value by 0.1 or 0.001 according to degree of decimal value in java

Tags: java, string, floating-point, decimal, bigdecimal

I have a decimal number eg 65.435 or 9.2 or 10.23 , now i have to increment it as 65.436, 9.3,10.24.

Is there any utility method present for that in java?

I know we can do it by checking decimal place and then increment, but i want like in case of integer if we use '++' it increment the value.

Can anyone suggest a better way to handle.

Comment: why not `double incrementer = 0.01; result += incrementer `

Comment: Use BigDecimal for precision calculation. Then you can just add.

Comment: I don't think there is an inbuilt way. What's the type of your input? String, double?

Comment: double is the input type

Comment: @Mr.Robot could you please help me with an example using my use case

Comment: Note that you will get precision problems with this; not all decimal numbers can be represented accurately by the type `double`. As Mr.Robot says, if you need precision, use BigDecimal.

Comment: @Alex No this will not work as I dont know the digits after decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spelling out Mr.Robot's comment:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.234");
bd = new BigDecimal(bd.unscaledValue().add(BigInteger.ONE), bd.scale());
```